# Laravel localization and routes from Jetstream / Fortify

Tags: laravel, localization, laravel-8, laravel-localization, laravel-jetstream

I have this new Laravel project to work on. We would like to make it available in multiple languages.

I started the project with JetStream. Routes for authentication and such are automatically handled by JetStream / Fortify. I then added https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization to handle the localization. it works fine for the routes I created myself :

```
Route::group(
    [
        'prefix' => LaravelLocalization::setLocale(),
        'middleware' => [ 'localeSessionRedirect', 'localizationRedirect', 'localeViewPath' ]
    ], function()
{
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    });

    Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified'])->get('/dashboard', function () {
        return view('dashboard');
    })->name('dashboard');
});
```

But how can I set the group, prefix and middleware on the routes handled by Jetstream and Fortify?

[EDIT]

So after some suggestions from @TEFO, I'm trying to add a middleware to handle setting the locale. Added :

Fortify.php :

```
    'path' => '{lang}',
    'middleware' => ['web', 'setLang']
```

new middleware setLang :

```
class SetLang {
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param \Closure $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request, Closure $next) {
        // $lang = 'en';
        // $request->attributes->add(['lang' => 'en']);
        $request->route()->setParameter('lang', 'en');
        // $request->request->set('lang', 'en');

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Added the middleware to `$routeMiddleware`.

I'm receiving this error when trying to reach `http://mylaravel/en/login` :

```
ErrorException
Missing required parameters for [Route: login] [URI: {lang}/login]. (View: /var/www/resources/views/auth/login.blade.php)
```

Comment: maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/a/64003630/7908390

Comment: I saw this but it's not really the same... It's a fixed prefix where I need a variable one

Comment: i know. but what you can do is put a parameter prefix like /{lang} and fill it with a middleware.

Comment: Interesting! Apparently I can define what middleware to use in the `fortify` config file as well. But it wouldnt work for the routes defined in jetstream, right?

Comment: Fortify has a `'prefix' => config('fortify.path'),` in its `FortifyServiceProvider`, Jetstream hasn't.

Comment: yes currently you cant define a prefix for jetstream but you can make you own route. the main package that do real authentication is fortify so if you have to customize your a lot or dont work with livewire and inertia jetstream is not a fit for your project

Comment: Okay. I will think about it. Let's just get back to your suggestion for a moment. How would you fill the {lang} in a middleware? I edited my question with what I tried.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Finally successfully nailed this. I simply disabled routes from Fortify and Jetstream, copied them over and shoved them inside my grouped prefix routes. Still using https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization but it should work anyway you want it - make your own system or whatever, as long as you control the routes you're good to go.

In **JetstreamServiceProvider** :

```
public function register() {
        Jetstream::ignoreRoutes();
    }
```

In **FortifyServiceProvider** :

```
public function register() {
        Fortify::ignoreRoutes();
    }
```

And copy over routes from Fortify `vendor/laravel/fortify/routes/routes.php` and Jetstream `vendor/laravel/jetstream/routes/livewire.php` (I guess adapt to Inertia if you're working with this) over to your `web.php` file, inside a route group with the prefix you need.

Comment: Yes, and make sure to add this to the `register` function, not to the `boot` function (as [sometimes](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/proper-way-to-override-jetstreamfortify-auth-routes) suggested) as that will be "too late".

Comment: You don't have c&p all routes. We can easly include them.
   

            Route::group([
                'namespace' => 'Laravel\Fortify\Http\Controllers',
            ], function () {
                require(base_path('vendor/laravel/fortify/routes/routes.php'));
            });

Answer (score 4):

I faced almost the same problem with the expection that i do not use [mcamara/laravel-localization](https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization) at the moment.

Based on the useful discussion above between [@JeremyBelolo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1928380/jeremy-belolo) and [@TEFO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7908390/tefo), the following solution worked for me:

1. Added `'path' => '{locale}/my-secret-path'` to `config/fortify.php`. As @JeremyBelolo and @ETO discussed, [the support for that was recenlty added](https://github.com/laravel/fortify/commit/5b68d94e93681ccaadab30ff2ee7d3cce0f805cc#diff-5a97b339563966253dac9f04ddaad63fe94adca0b061228e919589d2ead2ee9c).
2. Added my middleware before `\Laravel\Jetstream\Http\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class` to the `web` `$middlewareGroups`
3. Where my middleware set the locale `app()->setLocale($locale);` and the default {locale} url parameter `URL::defaults(['locale' => $locale]);` before passing the request deeper into the application.

Considering Jetstream I had to apply the same steps as [@JeremyBelolo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1928380/jeremy-belolo) did, exept I didn't copy the jetsream/livewire routes but used the following inside the route group:

```
require base_path('vendor/laravel/jetstream/routes/livewire.php');
```

Now I can access `{locale}/my-secret-path/login` where `{locale}` is a supported locale for my site.

**UPDATE [Fortify config option changed]**:

The `path` [fortify config option changed](https://github.com/laravel/fortify/commit/673f59c4918b59ea9ba8d0042e3b2aec331c52dd#diff-5a97b339563966253dac9f04ddaad63fe94adca0b061228e919589d2ead2ee9c) to `prefix`. Thus in `config/fortify.php` the following key should be used:

`'prefix' => '{locale}/my-secret-path'`

Answer (score 2):

I made a new Laravel Project using Jetstream. I wanted to use multi-language support in my project, but when I used Prefix (`en/login`, `de/login`) according to languages in `url`, I was also having a problem with Route. I solved my problem by following these steps. I hope you will be useful too:

1 - I have included the package on this https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization in my project. and followed the instructions sequentially.

2 - I made the Route settings in the "rautes\web.php" file as follows.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => LaravelLocalization::setLocale(),'middleware' => [ 
'localeSessionRedirect', 'localizationRedirect','localeViewPath' ]], function(){

/** ADD ALL LOCALIZED ROUTES INSIDE THIS GROUP **/
Route::get('/', function () {return view('welcome');});

Route::middleware(['auth', 'verified'])->get('/dashboard', function () {
    return view('back.dashboard');})->name('dashboard');
});
```

3 - I have included the in `app\Http\Middleware\Kernel.php`. In `middlewareGroups` end of `web` prefix.

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [....
     \Mcamara\LaravelLocalization\Middleware\LaravelLocalizationRoutes::class,            
     \Mcamara\LaravelLocalization\Middleware\LaravelLocalizationRedirectFilter::class,
     \Mcamara\LaravelLocalization\Middleware\LocaleSessionRedirect::class,
     \Mcamara\LaravelLocalization\Middleware\LocaleCookieRedirect::class,
     \Mcamara\LaravelLocalization\Middleware\LaravelLocalizationViewPath::class,]
```

4 - Fortify Routes, include `prefix` in `vendor\laravel\fortify\routes.php` - `Route::group` like this:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => LaravelLocalization::setLocale(),
'middleware' => config('fortify.middleware', ['web'])], function () {
$enableViews = config('fortify.views', true);
.......
```

5 - Livewire Routes, include `prefix` in `vendor\laravel\jetstream\routes\livewire.php` - `Route::group` like this:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => LaravelLocalization::setLocale(),
'middleware' =>config('jetstream.middleware', ['web'])], function () {
if (Jetstream::hasTermsAndPrivacyPolicyFeature()) {

Route::get('/terms-of-service', [TermsOfServiceController::class, 'show'])- 
>name('terms.show');
    
Route::get('/privacy-policy', [PrivacyPolicyController::class, 'show'])- 
>name('policy.show');}
```

6 - If you want to separate backend and frontend, you can add in `app\Http\Middleware\Kernel.php` end of `protected $routeMiddleware` with `prefix` like in this  https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization.

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
........
    'localize'=> \Mcamara\LaravelLocalization\Middleware\LaravelLocalizationRoutes::class,
    'localizationRedirect' => \Mcamara\LaravelLocalization\Middleware\LaravelLocalizationRedirectFilter::class,
    'localeSessionRedirect' => \Mcamara\LaravelLocalization\Middleware\LocaleSessionRedirect::class,
    'localeCookieRedirect' => \Mcamara\LaravelLocalization\Middleware\LocaleCookieRedirect::class,
    'localeViewPath'     => \Mcamara\LaravelLocalization\Middleware\LaravelLocalizationViewPath::class,
]
```

7 - And the happy end...

Answer (score 1):

I know this might be old issue, but I'm still facing it so my solution was to go to
`app\Providers\FortifyServiceProvider.php` and add `configureRoutes` protected method to the `boot` method and override the method as following:

```php
public function boot(): void
{
    $this->configureRoutes();
    // The rest of the boot method code
}

// override the configureRoutes method as following

protected function configureRoutes()
{
    if (Fortify::$registersRoutes) {
        Route::group([
            'namespace' => 'Laravel\Fortify\Http\Controllers',
            'domain' => config('fortify.domain', null),
            'prefix' => LaravelLocalization::setLocale(),
        ], function () {
               $this>loadRoutesFrom(base_path('vendor/laravel/fortify/routes/routes.php'));
        });
    }
}
```